# MySQL JSON output to webpage

Tags: mysql, json, express

I've got an Express node server which renders data from a MySQL database.

How would you go and turn this output into a webpage? As of now it's just JSON, how can I display fx. an html page instead with the data?

I know this is a stupid question.

```js
app.get("/get-cars", function (req, res) {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(results);
    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send an html response to the client instead of the JSON response you can use HTML template engine.

Let me show you an example with [Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

Step 1: Run `npm install --save handlebars`

Step 2: Create a file `cars.hbs` in your project's root directory

Step 3: Add the following code in your `cars.hbs` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Cars</title>
    <style>
      html {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
     }

      body {
        position: relative;
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
    </head>


    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Engine Size</th>
            <th>Accelaration</th>
            <th>Top Speed</th>
            <th>Consumption</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each cars}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{this.name}}</td>
                <td>{{this.enginesize}}</td>
                <td>{{this.maxpower}}</td>
                <td>{{this.accelaration}}</td>
                <td>{{this.topspeed}}</td>
                <td>{{this.consumption}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
       </table>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Step 4: In your js file (which contains the `get/cars` api) add the following code

```
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const fs = require("fs");
app.get("/get-cars", function (req, res) {
   let sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";
   let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
       if(err) throw err;
       const data = { cars: result };
       const template = fs.readFileSync("./cars.hbs", "utf8");
       const html = handlebars.compile(template)(data);
       res.send(html);
   });
});
```

Step 5: Open your browser and visit `http://localhost:3000/get-cars`

Alternatively, you can call your API from front-end and display the data in the browser using formatting of your choice.

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I had in mind, but couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Great. Do accept and upvote the answer if this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should work properly, it should display the JSON Array as a webpage

```
res.send(results);
```

just try to open your web browser and go to [localhost:3000/get-cars](http://localhost:3000/get-cars) , unless you want to display the result in another format, can you please clarify what's the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called as an **template engine**. Just like how we can emit html in php, template engines help server construct a page and return as html.

I would like to introduce you to pug as simple templating engine for express.

```
npm install -S pug
```

Create a new file called `template.pug` :

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title="cars data with pug"
  body
    h1 My Cars 
    #container.col
    ul
       each val in dbResult
          li= val.name
```

And inside your express server:

```
var pug = require("pug");

app.get("/get-cars", function (req, res) {
    const compiledFunction = pug.compileFile("template.pug");
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";
    let query = db.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
         res.send(
          compiledFunction({
           dbResult: sql
         })
    });
});
```

Voila! You should be seeing your html. I will leave out some fun for you and also few links

1. [pug's documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html).
2. https://github.com/pugjs/pug

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I had in mind, but couldn't wrap my head around it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, from your question i assume that you are well versed with the back-end side of things but need some help in familiarizing with front-end / rendering frameworks.

As a lot of developers would tell you, there are many ways to kill a cat in this case so i will recommend some frameworks and libraries to get you started:

**Recommendations:**
- Angular 4+ (my personal favourite),
- React,
- Vue
are very good front-end frameworks that you can get started with in order to build comprehensive Single Page Applications that are easy to scale up AND down. Please note that there are many OTHER front-end frameworks that one can choose from.

Knowing how to use Javascript is a must though in order to manipulate the DOM by rendering fetched data from the server (as in your case), so i will give you two eXamples of how to do this using native JS and JQuery as a library

1)

```js
// initiate your request
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// check if the server has responded with a status code of 200 after the request has been made
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
    results = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    // the easiest workaround is to build the html string and then inject it into the tbody
    // the best approach would be to createElements and inject them as you loop through the retuned data
    
    // using the easiest approach
    myString = "";
    for (i = 0; i < results; i++) {
      myString += "<tr><td>" + results[i].jsonElementForHeader1 + "</td><td>" + results[i].jsonElementForHeader2 + "</td></tr>";
    }
    // put the generated stuff from the request into the table body as table rows
    tbody = document.getElementById("tbody").innerHTML = myString
  }
};

// Add an event listener that checks the progress of the request once initiated
xhr.addEventListener('progress', evt => {
  if ( evt.lengthComputable ) {
    const perc = evt.loaded / evt.total * 100;
    // log the percentage to the console for monitoring (or render it the way you want)
    console.log(perc);
  }
}, false);

// specify the method and URL that you would want to query
xhr.open('POST', 'http://your.domain:port/script', true);
// important, if you are using cookies,
xhr.withCredentials = true;
// initiate the request
xhr.send(res1);
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thingy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>header 1</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>header 2</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id = 'theTableBody'>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

2)

```js
// launch your request to the server
$.post('http://your.domain:port/APIHandler', {'query': 'parameter(s) JSON Style'}, function(data) {
  // looping through the returned data to handle insertion of the data
  // we will use the recommended way this time round, but generating strings
  tbody = document.getElementById('theTableBody');
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     element = document.createElement("tr");
     element.innerHTML = "<td>" + data[i].desiredElementName1 + "</td><td>" + data[i].desiredElementName2 + "</td>";
     tbody.appendChild(element);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Thingy</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label>header 1</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <label>header 2</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id = 'theTableBody'>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone has a pretty strategy to get this information, I would say, use [Pipes + Modala](https://github.com/wise-penny/pipes).

<carousel id="get-cars" class="modala" ajax="foo.bar.json"></carousel>

There's a "filter" for making CRUD requests too. Very easy.

done.

There's a demonstration of just a few of the utilities in it at [g0d.me/pipes](http://g0d.me/pipes)